# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed even i have allowed filetype in config

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3 and i want to upload .cdr file. I have also allowed in cofig. Below is the code for that:

```
$config = array(
            'upload_path' => "./uploads/job_images/",
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|cdr|ai|psd|zip",
            'overwrite' => FALSE,
            // 'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
            // 'max_height' => "768",
            // 'max_width' => "1024"
             );

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

I have also checked in mimes.i got this for cdr:

```
'cdr'   =>  array('application/cdr', 'application/coreldraw', 'application/x-cdr', 'application/x-coreldraw', 'image/cdr', 'image/x-cdr', 'zz-application/zz-winassoc-cdr'),
```

but still i am getting an error like **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**

Comment: uhm could it be the final ,?

Comment: Yess. It is the problem.

Comment: Huh, what a mess can an extra , can make

Comment: I have added code from mimes.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the actual problem. I checked the mime type of file using $FILES['userfile']['type']. I got **application/octet-stream** as output which was not in allowed mime types.